# Разбивка таблицы

Tags: mysql

В одном сайте я использовал модуль "комментарии". Потом я прикинул, что если в день у меня будет примерно по 5 постов, в каждом посте по 10 коментов и умножаем на 365. Я имею в среднем 18 тыс. комментариев в год. Я подумал и подправил модуль: хранил данные не в одной таблице, а в нескольких (comments_2012, comments_2011 и тд), все таблицы создаются динамически, работает быстро, выбрка таблицы берется в зависимости от того, когда был написан пост, время на генерирование страницы на хостинге около 0.012 секунд. Все летает, все отлично. Но сейчас призадумался и посмотрел на одном моем сайте каталог продукции из 142 тыс и все грузится также быстро.

Так вот вопрос, а нужна ли это разбивка на таблицы, может я экономлю на копейках и ищу только лишние проблемы?

Comment: русский народ на этот случай говорит - на г..е сметану собирать

Comment: @Александр Лукин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ищете лишние проблемы. Если бы БД(MySql, небось?) не справлялась с 20+к записей, она не имела бы смысла.

Основная проблема начинается, когда используется Join. Вот тут да: полное однократное отображение  такой таблицы саму на себя(или на такую же) - это  20к*20к, то есть 400М. Это уже серьезно, хотя множество механизмов оптимизации тщательно стараются это число уменьшить.

У вас же проблема начнется, когда вы затеете глобальный поиск по всем комментариям. На один поиск число запросов будет в худшем случае кратно числу таблиц. оно вам надо?

Comment: Да это я уже расматривал
Также столкнулся с такой проблемой как: перед новым годом запостил тему, а потом, после нового года, добавил комментарий в этом посте. Дальше таблица содержит комментарии за 2012 год, а комментарии с 2013 года. 
Еще проблема в личном кабинете, когда пользователь хочет посмотреть свои комментарии. Не понятная выборка, я реализовал как "текущий год" - 5 и циклом вывел все содержимое за эти периоды, если такие таблицы существует, но допустим в таблице 2011, могут быть комментарии с 2012 :(

Comment: Если даже у вас древовидные комменты, используйте одну таблицу и не парьтесь.
Лучше оптимизировать запрос, чем разбивать на много таблиц.
Например, выборка всей ветки до определенного комментария на больших таблицах лучше делать в несколько запросов, количество которых соответствует степени вложенности, чем использовать один запрос с джойнами, который почти гарантированнно положит БД, особенно при поиске.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот не понимаю вообще смысла такого разбития! Если уж так хочется разбить на несколько таблиц - пользуйтесь view - простое ограничение на таблицу по годам с проиндексированными полями выдаст результат не медленнее, а думаю даже быстрее Вашего варианта. А возможностей намного больше.

Мне кажется что таким ручным разбиением Вы пытаетесь делать работу за СУБД.  Я понимаю ещё если этот метод использовать для экономии места для индексов, или на СУБД типа access'a 
который ещё mdb,  но даже он с такими задачами справлялся на ура.

А join тоже не проблема - надо просто оптимизировать запрос и задачу, нежели пытаться делать работу за базу